# React-native html parsing w. ticket-cookie

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, react-native

I am attempting to parse data from a source, that which authenticates datarequests by linking sessionIds with a validated ticketId, so that only a session with a sessionId corresponding to the right ticketId cookie will be verified.

Parsing public html and displaying it in a presentable format is easy enough, but I'm clueless as to how I should get an html doc, that which has the data unlocked by a verifed sessionId.

I can do a POST request, which will hand me a ticketId json string, but how do I use this to retrieve a 'locked' webpage?

In advance, thank you,

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I wish to make an app displaying the data - it is harvested from a schools studentsystem.

Comment: Is data coming from third party? what is the format of data?